# Why am I getting 'Script error' - Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want monthly average radiance composite images using nighttime data from the Visible Infrared Imaging Radiometer Suite (VIIRS) Day/Night Band (DNB) for Mopti region. I'm able to export the result to drive, however, after some time has elapsed I get this message 'Script error' in the print console. How can I rectify this?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-11-01', '2019-12-31'));
var nighttime = dataset.select('avg_rad');
var nighttimeVis = {min: 0.0, max: 60.0};
Map.centerObject(mopti, 8);
Map.addLayer(nighttime, nighttimeVis, 'Nighttime');

print(nighttime.first());

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: nighttime.first().clip(mopti),
  description:'Mopti_NightLight_November',
  folder: 'VIIRS_Night_Light_2019_Monthly_Data',
  scale: 400,
  region: mopti
});
```

Comment: How can you assert that the script works fine if it raises an error? Did you run it several times and got the errors just the last times? Further details on the error would be useful. Besides these questions a tip: add a description of what you want to do with that script, that'll help more expert users to guide you to a possibly more efficient way to reach your objective.

Comment: @F.H. Thank you. I've edited my post describing what I intend to do. Yes, I've run the script mutiple times and sometimes I get the error, sometimes I don't. It's been happening with my other scripts too.

Comment: I am not able to recreate the error myself with choosing a random study area, it sounds like you might be using a very large area and a too-small study scale which could overload the GEE servers sometimes, I suggest using a smaller study area or a larger study scale.